# React native nativebase checkbox: Text inside a checkbox going out of the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, checkbox, native-base

I cant make it work, text inside a checkbox (nativebase) is not shrinking, does anyone knows why? Am i missing some flex properties?

```
import React from "react"
import {Box, Center, Checkbox, Heading, NativeBaseProvider, Text} from "native-base"

export const List = () => {
    return (
        <Box mb="10%" mt="30%" width="80%" height="80%" maxHeight="80%">
            <Checkbox value={"superlongipermegatest"}>
                <Text mx="2">
                    superlongipermegatest
                </Text>
            </Checkbox>
        </Box>
    )
}

export default () => {
    return (
        <NativeBaseProvider>
            <Center
                flex={1}
                px="1">
                <List/>
            </Center>
        </NativeBaseProvider>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Checkbox` in a `Box`: `<Box width="100%">` this will restrict the contents to its parents and wrap the text.

```
<Box mb="10%" mt="30%" width="80%" height="80%" maxHeight="80%">
    <Box width="100%">
        <Checkbox value={"superlongipermegatest"}>
            <Text mx="2">
                superlongipermegatest
            </Text>
        </Checkbox>
    </Box>
</Box>
```